# When searching for ports with the f# tasks the result is always empty

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, search

When searching stackoverflow for posts with the tag c# you get all the posts,
but when searching with the tag f# you get nothing.

If you search fsharp you'll get lots of posts with an f# tag.

I'm guessing there is an exception for the c# tag but it has not yet been added for f# ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23

If you want to search for a tag, encase it in square-brackets, like this:

> [f#]

Also, keyword searches for the top 20 tags are converted to tag searches automatically, so searching with the keyword `c#` is the same as searching for `[c#]`.

Comment: Ah... ok now I see. It's kinda confusing the search is influenced by the selected tab even though the search box is "above" the tabs. But now I know, thank you.